# Specific reports from civicase

Tags: civicase, search

We have developed a sophisticated and fairly detailed *civicase*. However, we are having some difficulties in using *Advanced Search* to produce detailed reports based on some of the fields we have created in *Activity Types* f... or use in *Timelines*.

Is it that we are trying to do something that is not possible ... or that we haven't found out how to do it.

Comment: Dave - can you expand on what you mean by 'some difficulties' preferably with a recipe for how to replicate so anyone could hop on to the Demo site and set it up? (a minimised version just to look at the key concepts)

Comment: If you are using Drupal then Views might be your friend here.